# How to maintain action creator types in connected components with Redux, React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, casting, redux

I'm struggling to keep my actions in connected components type-safe.

Basically when I import a bunch of redux action creators, wrap them with the dispatcher using `react-redux` and pass them as props to a component, I'd like the resulting actions to maintain the original type information from the imported functions.

Actions have types and return type is inferred:

```
export const actionA = (p1: string, p2: number) =>
  ({ type: 'EXAMPLE_A', payload: { p1, p2 } })

export const actionB = (p1: number) =>
  ({ type: 'EXAMPLE_B', payload: p1 })
```

But my component still has some `any` types to satisfy the compiler, losing type safety.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Dispatch, bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as exampleActions from '../actions/example'

interface MyComponentProps {
  someStore: SomeStoreState,
  actions: any // <-- Just use whatever types exampleActions have?
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, {}> {

  constructor(props: MyComponentProps) {
    super(props)
  }

  private foo() {
    const { actionA } = this.props.actions.exampleActions
    actionA('foo', 'bar') // <-- Compile time error pls
  }


  public render() {
    return null
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  someStore: state.someStore
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => ({
  actions: {
    exampleActions: bindActionCreators<any>(exampleActions, dispatch)
  }
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Declaring the function parameter types again in the props interface sorta helps, but I'd just like to maintain the original types so they are defined in one place.

I don't really care about the types within the dispatcher itself, so somehow casting the `exampleTypes` (and any other actions') type information to the props would be a good enough solution for me, as if the dispatch binding wasn't there at all and the creators themselves were passed as props.

Additionally, the application is using `redux-promise-middleware`, which means some actions may return promises. I'd also want that information to be preserved, so actions can be chained within the component. But I think with casting that shouldn't be an issue to begin with.

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly type your action creators, then import their types along with the functions themselves.  Creating some generic action interfaces can help with this, as typically I find the redux types themselves unhelpful.  It is a little verbose, but the type support is often worth it, especially as you can get excellent typings within your reducers as well.

I typically use something like this for the actions/creators:

```
export interface TypedAction<TAction, TPayload> {
     type: TAction;
     payload: TPayload;
}

export type TypeA = "EXAMPLE_A";
export type TypeB = "EXAMPLE_B";

export interface PayloadA {
    p1: string;
    p2: number;
}

export interface PayloadB {
    p1: number;
}

export type ActionA = TypedAction<TypeA, PayloadA>;
export type ActionB = TypedAction<TypeB, PayloadB>;

export type Actions = ActionA | ActionB;

export type ActionCreatorA = (p1: string, p2: number) => ActionA;

export type ActionCreatorB = (p1: number) => ActionB;

export const actionCreatorA: ActionCreatorA = (p1, p2) => ({
    type: "EXAMPLE_A", 
    payload: {
        p1,
        p2
    }
});    

export const actionCreatorB: ActionCreatorB = (p1) => ({
    type: "EXAMPLE_B", 
    payload: {
        p1
    }
});
```

Which can be used in a component as:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Dispatch, bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { 
    actionCreatorA, ActionCreatorA,
    actionCreatorB, ActionCreatorB
} from '../actions/example'

interface MyComponentProps {
    someStore: SomeStoreState;
    actionCreatorA: ActionCreatorA;
    actionCreatorB: ActionCreatorB;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: MyComponentProps) {
        super(props)
    }

    private foo() {
        const { actionA } = this.props;
        actionA('foo', 'bar') // <-- Compiles
    }


    public render() {
        return null
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    someStore: state.someStore
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    actionCreatorA
};

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Reducers can also benefit by using:

```
import ( Actions } from "./actions/example";

// Actions here is the union type of all actions this reducer will
// handle, as exported from the actions file
export const someReducer = (state = defaultState, action: Actions) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "EXAMPLE_A":
            // action is typed as ActionA
            return {
                p1: action.p1,
                p2: action.p2
            };
        case "EXAMPLE_B":
            // action is typed as ActionB
            return {
                p1: action.p1,
                p2: action.p2  // <-- Does not compile, p2 does not exist on ActionB
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```